# No menu button when theme is set

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

when I set a theme within my app, the menu-button (the three dots) isn't shown any more.

This is my style-definition (I'm just pulling the Android-defaults):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <style name="DarkTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black">
 </style>
 <style name="LightTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
 </style>
</resources>
```

it is set in **onCreate();**

```
setTheme(R.style.LightTheme)
```

What do I have to do to not to let the menu button disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two case here,

1> MainActivity extends Activity with native theme

2> MainActivity extends AppcompatActivity with your custom theme not native theme

use below code to do not let overmenu disapper

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/attachMain"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Attachment" />

</menu>
```

if your MainActivity extends Activity not AppcompatActivity and you are using **android: Theme.Light** native theme 
so, you can just replace

`app:showAsAction="always"` with `android:showAsAction="always"`